# Sending ACK in socket C#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I need to send files to a server through Socket. The server will send ACK for every message i send. If i didn't receive the ACK within 30sec I'll have to send the request again.

My question is, how to send/receive the ACK? Is there any internal ACK or should the server send ACK in bytes? As per my understanding, the server here will not send ACK as message. So i want to know how to handle this ACK part.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a ACK in TCP however it is at a level that you (nor the server) can touch and use. If you are using TCP you shouldn't need to do this anyway (unless your server intentionally drops packets) as TCP is guaranteed delivery. So my question is are you using UDP or is your server doing something special that requires the seccond ACK?

Comment: Am not using UDP. Server has provided me this information about the ACK, that i'll have to wait for 30 sec for ACK. The same thing prevails at their end. If i don't send ACK they'll send it again. They have provided me a diagram which shows with arrow mark but they hav'nt provided me what the ACK is. So i want to know is there any other way that i can handle this ACK?

Comment: Without knowing what they are sending or what they are expecting of you it would be hard to recommend what to do, as a one byte acknowledgment is a lot different than calculating and returning the CRC of the last payload.

Comment: Thanks for that information. So if the server is sending ACK, will that be a ACK apart from internal TCP ACK?

Comment: You are asking at the wrong place. Ask the guy that's responsible for that particular *server*'s (whatever it actually is) communication API.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have a doubt of how to keep socket active. My flow is this. Incoming File-->Class A-->Class B-->Send/Receive through Socket. Now my doubt is i'll keep getting files and how do i use the same socket without closing the connection?

Comment: @Vinoth Khanna if they are using the term ACK then mostlikey yes. You need to go back and ask the person providing the server API. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Reliable_transmission

Comment: @Vinoth Khanna the stream you get from your connection is normally duplex. Which means you can send and receive at the same time on the same stream.

Comment: Hi Scott, Say all the variables in Class B will be initialised on entering Class B. If i return the response, all the variables will lose its memory. Again when the request comes, i need to pass it on to Class B and i dont want to initialise the variables again. I want to use the same connection which i used sometime back. Is this possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a protocol that started life when used with serial ports.  Which don't have the kind of delivery and error checking guarantee that's built into TCP.  If the 'packet' you have to send has something like a CRC or checksum then that's a dead ringer for such a protocol.

Adding this kind of checking isn't necessary for TCP.  It will probably work just fine when you simply blast the file and not pay any attention to the ACKs.  Although you ought to read them to prevent the buffer from filling.  A secondary way is to simply wait for *something* being sent back from that server before sending the next chunk of bytes.

If you want to check the ACK anyway then look for a single byte with the value 6, the default ASCII control code for an ACK.  I wouldn't implement the 'resend when timeout' feature unless the protocol implements a 'block number' that helps it detect duplicate blocks, that's just likely to fail on the receiving end with double the data.  Just send the next chunk.

Comment: Hi Hans, do you have any code samples to check for the single byte value 6? After sending the message in bytes, how do i check for this single byte?

Comment: That's a bit too basic to come up with anything that would be helpful.  Use Socket.Receive().  Ask for help from your team members, sounds like you could use some.

Comment: Thanks for that Hans. Yes am pretty new to this socket connectivity. Thanks.